# Facebook SDK - Get access token programatically

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have a web application made with PHP and when I submit a particular form, I want to publish to my Facebook fan page.
You can see the below code:

```
    $appId = "...";
    $appSecret = "...";
    $version = "v2.5";

    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => $appId,
        'app_secret' => $appSecret,
        'default_graph_version' => $version,
    ]);

    $accounts = $fb->get("/me/accounts");
    $pages = $accounts->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
```

With that code I have the  `FacebookSDKException` saying that `You must provide an access token.` 
I have not found a way to generate the access token programatically just using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer.
My composer:

```
"require": {
        "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "~5.0"
}
```

How can I get an access token programatically/automatically? Or what alternative do you suggest?

Comment: I believe your u need to authorize to get the access token returned https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: The web application to publish (Share a link)  as an admin fan page in my fan page. shouldn't display any popup for login in facebook. How can I authorize?

Comment: You _need_ to send the user to the FB login dialog. You need to do it only once though, if you get an extended page token. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens has all the necessary details.

Comment: @CBroe It makes no sense show a login dialog to my users because my web app should publish on my own fan page automatically as admin. My users doesn't need login to facebook.

Comment: You need to send the page admin through the login flow at least once. Whether you want to _implement_ that in your application, or create the token outside of it (by performing the necessary requests “manually”) is up to you.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm confused and I don't understand what do you mean with "at least once". Can you show me a sample?

Comment: You need to ask the page admin for permission to post as the page – and that you need to do at least once (if you get an extended page token afterwards, that does not have any default expiry time.)

Answer (score 3):

here is what I did.
For start use the code of the JS SDK [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens)

If response.status===connected(find that expression in the code) obtain the access token with this code:

```
 var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
```

then redirect to a page where PHP code resides and in the url attach the access_token...like this:

```
  window.location = "http://localhostfb_test.php?access_token="+accessToken;
```

In the server now use the token like this.

```
$user_profile = $fb->get('/me',$_GET['access_token']);
```

[here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens)

and in the section **Tokens are Portable** it is clearly mentioned that tokens can shipped from client to server...**this is what I do here**.

Comment: Overflow012....check this also https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookJavaScriptHelper/5.0.0

Comment: If you show the access token to public, is it prone to any hacking?